# django admin - You don't have permission to edit anything

Tags: django, django-admin

I followed the [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) on creating a custom user model while extending the model itself with my own fields. So it became like this:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=70, unique=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin

    def get_full_name(self):
        return ('%s %s') % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username

    objects = MyUserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'date_of_birth']
```

And its manager to be:

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, first_name, last_name, username, date_of_birth, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('User must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            username=username,
            date_of_birth=date_of_birth,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, first_name, last_name, username, date_of_birth, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            username=username,
            date_of_birth=date_of_birth,
            password=password
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

However, after I created the superuser while syncdb, when I login to the admin panel, there is nothing to do. It displays:

> > You don't have permission to edit anything.

I saw some other post with the same problem and most of them suggested to add `admin.autodiscover()` in the urls.py. But even this didn't help me.

This is the admin.py:

```
class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm

    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'date_of_birth', 'is_admin')
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': (('first_name', 'last_name'), 'username', 'date_of_birth')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin',)}),
    )

    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('Wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'date_of_birth')
        }),
    )
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()


admin.site.register(MyUser, MyUserAdmin)
```

What am I doing wrong here? Please help me how to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: I would inherit from `AbstractUser` not `AbstractBaseUser`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Answering my question here. So the problem was, PermissionsMixin. What I thought was that PermissionsMixin will handle all the permssion related things. But even though I added the PermissionsMixin to the new user Model, I had to explicitly make the tell django that the superuser is indeed superuser by adding `is_superuser` or by `has_perm`.

So I changed my function inside the User manager to

```
def create_superuser(self, email, first_name, last_name, username, date_of_birth, password, **kwargs):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            username=username,
            date_of_birth=date_of_birth,
            password=password,
            is_superuser=True,
            **kwargs
        )
```

Hope this will help someone like me!

Answer (score 3):

in 2020, you need to define two methods

```
def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
       return self.is_superuser
def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
       return self.is_superuser
```

also the model field is_superuser...you can rename the is_superuser field to is_admin or anything... for that case u will also need to change is_superuser to is_admin in your functions

Comment: These are defined in `PermissionsMixin`, which `AbstractUser` inherits from, so you should not need to set these up (assuming one doesnt rename is_superuser)

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was in venv. Try to recreate it